# Is there any way to optimize the following code without changing the logic and language ? Reason : Time limit exceeded in UVa

Tags: c, time, equation-solving, time-limiting

> **10110 - Light, more light**
>
> There is man named ”mabu” for switching on-off light in our University. He switches on-off the lights
> in a corridor. Every bulb has its own toggle switch. That is, if it is pressed then the bulb turns on. Another press will turn it off. To save power consumption (or may be he is mad or something else) he does a peculiar thing. If in a corridor there is n bulbs, he walks along the corridor back and forth n times and in i-th walk he toggles only the switches whose serial is divisable by i. He does not press any switch when coming back to his initial position. A i-th walk is defined as going down the corridor (while doing the peculiar thing) and coming back again. Now you have to determine what is the final condition of the last bulb. Is it on or off?
>
> **Input**
>
> The input will be an integer indicating the n’th bulb in a corridor. Which is less then or equals 2<sup>32</sup> −1. A zero indicates the end of input. You should not process this input.
>
> **Output**
>
> Output ‘yes’ if the light is on otherwise ‘no’, in a single line.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 3
> 6241
> 8191
> 0
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> no
> yes
> no
> ```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int n, a, d, i, j;
    while (1)
    {
        scanf("%u", &n);
        if (n == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        a = n / 2;

        d = 0;

        for (i = 1; i <= a; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                d++;
            }
        }
        if (d % 2 == 0)
        {
            printf("yes\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("no\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is that even possible in C ?
Not allowed to use any other language :(
Language they used : ANSI C 5.3.0 - GNU C Compiler with options: **-lm -lcrypt -O2 -pipe -ansi -DONLINE_JUDGE**

The run time should not exceed 3 seconds.

Comment: Time exceeded usually means you're using the wrong algorithm.

Comment: And please [edit] your question to make it self-contained, without the need for external third-party sites.

Comment: Also, just don't write code like that. Not even for such sites. What are the meaning of those variables? What is the code doing? Why is the code doing it the way it does? Use semantically significant variable names, and comment the code to document what it does and more importantly *why*.

Comment: You are surely not supposed to get the result by *simulating* the guy's endless walk, but by *computing* the result from the initial state.

Comment: All this is doing is telling you if the number is a perfect square or not.   If it's a perfect square, it prints "yes".  Otherwise it prints "no".  (See if you can figure out why it's equivalent to that.) So think of a fast way to test for that.  Forget about the light switches, that's a very slow way to do it.

Comment: @TomKarzes "All this is doing is telling you if the number is a perfect square or not." --> almost.  A bit unclear what should happen when `n` is a perfect square of 1.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of text.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica No, if `n` is 1, then the switch should be toggled.   Why do you think it's a special case?  It isn't.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica According to the problem statement, if `n` is 1, then it should be toggled:  On the first walk, he reaches switch 1.  Since 1 is divisible by 1, he toggles it.  Then he's done.  Not a special case.  This is a well-known problem.  There's no special case for 1.  The switch is turned on and remains on.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ok, I looked at OP's code.  It works, but it does use an inverted test.  The reason is because it always skips `n` itself, so the count is always one lower than the actual count.  But that isn't a problem, since it just inverts the sense of the test at the end.  So `d` is always one less than the total number of toggles for switch `n`.  And again, it prints "yes" for all perfect squares, including 1, and "no" for everything else.  There is no special case for 1.  Stopping past `n/2` always skips exactly one toggle, which is `n` itself.

Comment: @TomKarzes "why would you want to preserve those bugs?" --> OP specifically requested it with "Is there any way to optimize the following code without changing the logic and language ? Reason : Time limit exceeded in UVa".  So I offered [optimization ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77766898/2410359) to cope with the _Time limit exceeded_.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Right, but in fact there weren't any bugs in the code, so it's a moot point.  I was misled but your persistence in claiming that there is a special case for 1, which there isn't.  All that claim did was confuse the issue.  Again, there is nothing special about 1.  You were just misled by the fact that the loop always skips `n` itself (which is the only number beyond `n/2` that would cause a toggle.  You mistakenly thought that was a special case for 1.  It isn't.  My original comment was 100% correct.  Nothing more was needed on the subject.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256499/discussion-between-chux-reinstate-monica-and-tom-karzes).

Answer (score 2):

Looping to `n/2` is *very slow* as code only needs to loop to `sqrt(n)`.

```
    a=n/2;
    d=0;
    for (i=1; i<=a; i++) {
        if (n%i==0) {
          d++;
        }
    }
```

is replaceable with below which loops up to `sqrt(n)` times.

```
    d=0;
    if (n > 1) { 
      d += 1;
    }
    for (i=2; i < n/i; i++) {
        if (n%i==0) {
          d += 2;
        }
    }
    if (i == n/i) {
        if (n%i==0) {
          d += 1;
        }
    }
```

And since later code only needs the even-ness of `d`, the `for (i=1; i < a/i; i++) {` loop serves little other than to get `i` up to near the square root of `n`.  Consider testing if `n` is a perfect square instead and watch out for edge cases when `n <= 1`.  (Careful with `double sqrt(double)` as that may incur unexpected rounding.)

Note: do not use `...; i*i < n; i++` as `i*i` may overflow when `n` is a large value near `UINT_MAX`.

Pedantically, use a wider type that `unsigned`, which may have less range than needed.  Suggest `unsigned long`.